# dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting:

Tags: apt, upgrade, dpkg, raspberrypi

I'm having this problem when I'm installing the `apt-get upgrade` in my Raspberry Pi raspbian.

```
Reading changelogs... Done
Extracting templates from packages: 100%
dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting:
 files list file for package 'gir1.2-gdkpixbuf-2.0:armhf' is missing final newline
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

I don't know what to do, any help please I'm stuck on this.

Comment: Raspbian is not Ubuntu. You will probably have better success at 
the [RPi SE](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/) or the [Unix&Linux SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the mentioned files with

```
sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/info/gir1.2-gdkpixbuf-2.0*
```

Then reinstall the package with

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall gir1.2-gdkpixbuf-2.0
```

or

```
sudo dpkg -i --force-all /var/cache/apt/archives/gir1.2-gdkpixbuf-2.0*.deb
```

Comment: Ohhh man!!!! you are the VIP!!! thanks so much.... i was  about to go crazy with this... and this really worked...  thanks so much!! i wanna buy u a beer :D

Comment: Thank you! I hade the same issue with the package firmware-linux-free and your advice worked fine!